# WPGraphql get category posts count based on custom taxonomy

Tags: plugins

I want to execute a graphql to fetch the category count

```
{
  categories {
    nodes {
      databaseId
      name
      posts(where: {office_term_id: 5}) {
        pageInfo {
         total
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should display the post count that belongs to that category as well as office_term_id where office is custom taxonomy.

How to get this running?

Comment: What plug-in are you using to provide WPGraphL? You'll need to check with their support team.

Answer (score 1):

Setup WPGraphQL Offset Pagination and run:

```
query tags {
      tags {
        nodes {
          posts(where: {categoryId: 7}) {
            pageInfo {
              offsetPagination {
                total
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```